# Angular - ngFor performance issues

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a video application written in Angular 4. In this app, user can add a video and subtitles, and edit the videos captions on a list. the captions in list are always synced with the video current play time. When video current time change, the list viewport is changed in order to display the current caption. 
The number of captions always stay the same, user can not add or remove items only edit the caption text.
When having many captions (>500) the app is working very very slowly.
I thought about creating and destroying items in the ngFor according to the list viewport, but it seems to be to much work. 
Is there a better solution (Not using pagging)
[![

```js
import { Caption } from './caption';

export class Translation {
    public sourceCaption: Caption;
    public targetCaption: Caption;

    constructor(sourceCaption: Caption, targetCaption: Caption) {
        this.sourceCaption = sourceCaption;
        this.targetCaption = targetCaption;
    }

    get startTime() {
        return this.sourceCaption && this.sourceCaption.startTime;
    }

    get endTime() {
        return this.sourceCaption && this.sourceCaption.endTime;
    }
}


export class Caption{
    public startTime: number;
    public endTime: number;
    public text: Array<string>; 
    public id: String;
    public isFlag: Boolean;
    public isItalic: Boolean;
    public languageId: String;
    public clientId: String;

    constructor(clientId: String, languageId: String, id?: String, startTime?: number, endTime?: number, text?: Array<string>, isFlag?:Boolean, isBold?:Boolean, isItalic?: Boolean ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.clientId = id || clientId;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
        this.text = text || new Array<string>();
        this.isFlag = isFlag;
        this.languageId = languageId;
    }
}
```

```html
<!--list-->

<div class="tt-translations-list">
  <tt-translation-list-header></tt-translation-list-header>
  
  <div class="tt-translation-list-items-container" #container>
    <div class="tt-translation-list-item-container" 
        *ngFor="let translation of translations; trackBy:i; let i = index" 
        (click)="setEditMode(translation)">

        <tt-translations-list-item [index]="i"
                                   [translation]="translation">
        </tt-translations-list-item>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>



<!--list-item-->

<div class="tt-translations-list-item"
     #container
     [ngClass]="{'selected-row': isEditMode}"> 

     <div class="tt-translations-list-item-border-container"
          [ngClass]="{'visible': isEditMode}">
     </div>

     <div class="tt-translations-list-item-source-caption-container">
       <div class="source-caption-header">
          <tt-translations-list-item-header [caption]="translation.sourceCaption"
                                            [index]="index">
          </tt-translations-list-item-header>
       </div>

       <div class="source-caption-content-container"
            dir="auto">
          <span *ngFor="let line of translation?.sourceCaption?.text">
              {{line}}
          </span>
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tt-translations-list-item-target-caption-container">
       <div class="target-caption-content-container">
          <tt-target-caption-editor [editCaption]="translation.targetCaption">
          </tt-target-caption-editor>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image: ][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4OCR.png)

Comment: I would for sure add some sort of "pagination" to not preclude Angular from having to "worry" about rendering hundreds of items when you only need a few. To not have to "page" things as one normally would, you could instead add a type of "infinite scroll" behavior to achieve a similar outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to render the list in parts or only the visible captions. If this is not solution for you try to set change detection to 
`ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and set the click event on the parent element of the list, to avoid having thousand event clicks (for each row).
If your translations have ID's track by it `trackBy: trackByFn`

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return item.id
}
```

When you set changedetection `OnPush` you have to have always new instance of the array you provide to `*ngFor`, for ex:

```
let captions = [{id: 1, name: '1 caption'}];
// instead of 
captions.push({id: 2, name: 'new caption'});
// you have to do
captions = caption.concat({id: 1, name: 'new caption'});
```

or if you have object, avoid mutating it, because `OnPush` works by comparing references of the inputs of the component.
While you did not provide a reference to a new object/array but instead mutated an existing one, the `OnPush` change detector did not get triggered.

Comment: Hi Yordan,
Thank you very much for your help.
setting ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush prevent the list to render at all and nothing is being displayed. I didn't understand how you suggest how change to location of the click event handler?

Comment: I've updated my answer, about the change detection. If you add the code for `setEditMode` function maybe I can give you some solution for this ;].